FastStream KafkaRouter seems to ignore retry_backoff_ms option
Describe the bug:
I'm creating a subscriber in a FastAPI app using KafkaRouter.
When raising a NackMessage, the subscriber immediatly consumes back the failed message without any delay.
I tried to add the "retry_backoff_ms" option to my KafkaRouter but it does not change anything and no delay has been considered.
How to reproduce
The definition of my KafkaRouter :
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi_lifespan_manager import LifespanManager
from typing import AsyncIterator
from faststream.kafka.fastapi import KafkaRouter
from api.conf import get_kafka_settings

kafka_settings = get_kafka_settings()
router = KafkaRouter(bootstrap_servers=kafka_settings.url, retry_backoff_ms=100000)


def setup_kafka_router(lifespan: LifespanManager):
    @lifespan.add
    async def setup(app: FastAPI) -> AsyncIterator[None]:
        print("Connecting Kafka Router...")
        await router.broker.connect()
        yield

    lifespan.add(router.lifespan_context)
    return router

The subscriber :
@router.subscriber(
    "custom_topic", group_id="group", auto_commit=False, retry=True, auto_offset_reset="earliest"
)
async def handler(
    message: Any,
    logger: Logger,
    service: CustomService = Depends(),
):
    try:
        await service.process(message)
        AckMessage()  # Acknowledge the message
        logger.info("API call succeeded.")
    except CustomError as err:
        raise NackMessage()

Environment:
faststream -v
> Running FastStream 0.5.18 with CPython 3.10.2 on Linux

Thank you in advance
All config, switch between kafka router and confluent router.. same result
